# Array.IsReadOnly inconsistent depending on interface implementation

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, .net-3.5

A typed array implements both the `System.Collections.IList` and `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>` interfaces, which both have their own `IsReadOnly` properties. But what on earth is going on here?

```
var array = new int[10];
Console.WriteLine(array.IsReadOnly); // prints "False"

var list = (System.Collections.IList)array;
Console.WriteLine(list.IsReadOnly); // prints "False"

var collection = (System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<int>)array;
Console.WriteLine(collection.IsReadOnly); // prints "True"
```

The `IList` view of the array behaves as I'd expect, returning the same as the array itself, however the `ICollection<T>` view of the array returns true.

Is there any rational explanation for this behaviour, or is it a compiler/CLR bug? (I'd be really surprised if it's the latter as you'd imagine this would have been found before now, but it's so counter-intuitive I can't think what the explanation could be...).

I'm using C#3.0/.NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Interesting, the remarks for both say "A collection that is read-only does not allow the addition, removal, or modification of elements after the collection is created.".
And I would think that logic equates to
IsReadOnly = !CanAdd || !CanRemove || !CanEdit
which should return true because you can replace the value at a specified index of the list.

Comment: a but more, But Array.IsReadonly document is explicit..

"This property is always false for all arrays."

"Array implements the IsReadOnly property because it is required by the System.Collections..::.IList interface.

If you require a read-only collection, use a System.Collections class that implements the System.Collections..::.IList interface.

An array that is read-only does not allow the addition, removal, or modification of elements after the array is created."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was plenty of agony over this decision, as evident in the comments on this [feedback article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=96920).

Comment: Looks like this gives the internal reasoning (which appears to be "we know it's rubbish but it's too late in the release cycle to do anything about it"). So it's by design, but not a good one.

Comment: link to the feedback article appears to be broken. is there another link?

Answer (score 7):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx):

> IList is a descendant of the
>   ICollection interface and is the base
>   interface of all non-generic lists.
>   IList implementations fall into three
>   categories: read-only, fixed-size, and
>   variable-size. A read-only IList
>   cannot be modified. A fixed-size IList
>   does not allow the addition or removal
>   of elements, but it allows the
>   modification of existing elements. A
>   variable-size IList allows the
>   addition, removal, and modification of
>   elements.

The ICollection<T> interface does not have an indexer, so a fixed-size ICollection<T> is automatically readonly - there is no way to modify an existing item.

Possibly ICollection<T>.IsFixedSize would have been a better property name than ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly, but both imply the same thing - impossible to add or remove elements, i.e. the same as IList.IsFixedSize.

An array is a fixed-size list, but is not readonly as elements can be modified.

As an ICollection<T>, it is readonly, since an ICollection<T> has no way to modify elements.

This may appear confusing, but it is consistent and logical.

What is slightly inconsistent is that the generic IList<T> interface has an IsReadOnly property inherited from ICollection<T> whose semantics are therefore different from the non-generic IList.IsReadOnly.  I imagine the designers were aware of this inconsistency but were unable to go back and change the semantics of the non-generic IList for backwards compatibility reasons.

To summarize, an IList can be:

- Variable-size.

  IList.IsFixedSize = false

  IList.IsReadOnly = false

  ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly = false
- Fixed-size (but elements can be modified, e.g. an Array)

  IList.IsFixedSize = true

  IList.IsReadOnly = false

  ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly = true
- Read-only (elements can not be modified)

  IList.IsFixedSize = true

  IList.IsReadOnly = true

  ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly = true

Comment: This is a great perspective. I think the fundamental issue here is that for non-generic collections `IsReadOnly` property is on `IList`, where as for generic collections `IsReadOnly` is on `ICollection<T>`. That changes the whole meaning. Such oversight from designers. Of course all this mess could have been totally avoided if we had `IReadOnly` interfaces from the get go in .NET (no need of that property at all!).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior comes down to `System.Array` having 2 IsReadOnly properties

The first is a normal property on the type array.  This property satisfies the IsReadOnly property of the IList interface. For whatever reason in 1.0 of the CLR they deemed that the property should return true.

The second is the explicit property implementation for the type `ICollection<T>` (actually implemented by the CLR IIRC).  In this case IsReadOnly returns true because the type `Array` cannot satisfy the mutating methods of `ICollection<T>` such as Add, Clear, etc ...

The real question is why the change between versions?  I don't actually know but my guess is that the authors determined that it is more appropriate to view the `Array` as read only when it is seen as a separate collection.  While it can satisfy part of the mutable methods it cannot satisfy them all.  Hence it's safer to see it as readonly vs. mutable.

Comment: The explanation that `ICollection<T>.IsReadOnly` returns true because it can't satisfy all methods of the `ICollection<T>` interface doesn't really hold water because `IList.IsReadOnly` returns false and it can't satisfy all methods of the `IList` interface either. So I still don't know whether this is a bug, or if not what the rationale behind the decision was.

Comment: @Greg, I believe this represents a change in thinking between v1 and v2 of the CLR.  Likely due to customer complaints although I can't find any evidence of that.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for the [Array Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Array class implements the
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`,
>   `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The
>   implementations are provided to arrays
>   at run time, and therefore are not
>   visible to the documentation build
>   tools. As a result, the generic
>   interfaces do not appear in the
>   declaration syntax for the Array
>   class, and there are no reference
>   topics for interface members that are
>   accessible only by casting an array to
>   the generic interface type (explicit
>   interface implementations). **The key
>   thing to be aware of when you cast an
>   array to one of these interfaces is
>   that members which add, insert, or
>   remove elements throw**
>   `NotSupportedException`.

So, because the generic collections do not support add, insert, or delete, `IsReadOnly` returns true.
As to why it doesn't return false for `System.Collections.IList`?  My guess would be that

```
var array = new int[10];
Console.WriteLine(array.IsReadOnly); // prints "True"
array[0] = 5; // WTF? This is readonly.
```

was not what they wanted to see.  When they added the generics interfaces in v2, these can only be called when the array has been cast, so returning true for those made more sense.

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question at all; there is no justification for why the IsReadOnly property returns a different value for the underlying array.