# Remove an object from List of dynamic object

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

```
//Data is IList<ExpandoObject>
var result = (from dynamic item in Data
              where item.id== "123"
              select item).FirstOrDefault();
```

Want to achieve below feature but it is erroring out by saying remove not available for `dynamic` objects.

```
Data.Remove(result);
```

Let me know if any suggestions.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried casting `result` back to `ExpandoObject` when you pass it?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add dynamic to IList<T> fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240596/add-dynamic-to-ilistt-fails)

Answer (score 3):

> Error: remove not available for **dynamic** objects

base on [Microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_ICollection_1_Remove__0_), The `Remove` method of `IList<T>` accepts a parameter with the type of `T`:

```
ICollection<T>.Remove(T)
```

In your example, `T` is an `ExpandoObject`, so it means in the `Remove` method you should pass a parameter with the type of `ExpandoObject` but you didn't and you are passing a parameter with the type of `dynamic`. Therefore you facing this error

for resolving this you have two way:

1) Use explicit type instead of `var`:

```
ExpandoObject result = ...
```

2) cast the `result` when you are passing it to `Remove`:

```
Data.Remove((ExpandoObject) result)
```

I think with doing one of these ways, your problem will resolve. good luck.

Comment: The LINQ expression is casting `ExpandoObject` to `dynamic`, so as part of declaring `result` as `ExpandoObject` (#1), you would have to cast the result of the LINQ expression back to `ExpandoObject`.  #2 is probably easier to understand at a glance and is correct without modification.

Comment: _"so it means in the Remove method you should pass a parameter with the type of ExpandoObject but you didn't and you are passing a parameter with the type of dynamic"_  I'm not sure this is strictly accurate. The point of `dynamic` is exactly so that it can be passed instead of anything and that it gets resolved at run time. Note, that this (OP) works perfectly in .net 3.0, so I suspect that this is just a framework bug that got fixed in .net core.

Comment: See my comment to the OP for the original bug.